# Angular2 How to Embed Yammer Content

Tags: angular2-template, yammer

I am unable to Embed Yammer into my Application as it needs me to add a Script tag.

Angular2 will automatically clear all Script tags.

is there a way to integrate yammer with Angular2?

Answer (score 0):

i clearned this by adding Jquery into Angular2 code. Yuk! but did the trick

Answer (score 0):

In your outer .html file, add the reference to the Yammer library:

```
<!-- Embed Yammer -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import("app").catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Create a component.html file with this:

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Create a component.ts file with this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'yammer-tile',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'yammer-tile.component.html'
})
export class YammerTileComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {
        var yam: any = window['yam'];
        yam.connect.embedFeed({
            container: '#embedded-feed',
            network: '**yournetwork.com**',
            feedType: 'group',
            feedId: '**yourFeedId**'
        });
    }
};
```

[More Yammer config options here](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/embed)